# JQuery gallery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to design a page that has a JQuery gallery with descriptive text for each picture. The goal is to have the image centered and the descriptive text 5 pixels to the left. The issue I come across is that each picture is of varying width. I can't seem to get the descriptive text to stick next to the picture. What CSS do I need to use to make each "text" div be 5 px to the left of an img in each slide? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Each picture is supposed to be of varying width. The challenge is getting the text to change position horizontally accordingly

Here is the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#gallery').cycle({ 
    fx:     'none', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 15000, 
    next:   '#navrightarrow', 
    prev:   '#navleftarrow' 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#gallery').before('<div id="imgnav">').cycle({ 
                fx: 'none', 
                speed:  'slow', 
                timeout: 15000, 
                pager:  '#imgnav', 
                pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
                        var src = $('img',slide).attr('src');
                        src = src.substring(0, src.length - 8);
                        return '<a href="#"><img src="' + src + 'detail.jpg" width="30" height="30" /></a>'; 
                } 
        }); 

</script>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery_wrapper">
            <div id="gallery">
                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="text">
                        <h5>Lambent</h5>
                        <p>2002</p>
                        <p>Oil on Linen</p>
                        <p>60 x 46 inches</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="images/1 Lambent-detail.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/1 Lambent-full.jpg" alt="slide1"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="slide">
                    <div id="text">
                        <h5>Marsh Ikat</h5>
                        <p>2002</p>
                        <p>Oil on Linen<p>
                        <p>64 x 36 inches</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="images/2 Marsh-Ikat-detail.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/2 Marsh-Ikat-full.jpg" alt="slide2"></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: m also searching for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this just a hack really, but it gets the job done. I'd prefer if someone could tell me a better way to do this but what I did was assign a new div name to each text description and use position:relative; and then just move it according to where it needs to go for each picture. This took forever, but it worked.

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="text" id="mb1">
        <h5>Lambent</h5>
        <p>2002</p>
        <p>Oil on Linen</p>
        <p>60 x 46 inches</p>
    </div>
    <a href="images/marshes and ponds/Lambent-detail.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/marshes and ponds/Lambent-full.jpg" alt="slide1"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

About the varying width issue of images, only thing I know of is to use a wrapper like div.

```
<style>
  div.slide div.image_wrapper {
      width:  200px;    // define a fixed width
      height: 200px;    // define a fixed height here
      overflow: hidden; // this helps us have images behave of same size, without scaling 
    }
</style>


<div class="slide">
    <div class="text">     // You are repeating an ID text, have it as a class
        <h5>Marsh Ikat</h5>
        <p>2002</p>
        <p>Oil on Linen<p>
        <p>64 x 36 inches</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image_wrapper">
        <a href="images/2 Marsh-Ikat-detail.jpg" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/2 Marsh-Ikat-full.jpg" alt="slide2">
        </a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

The `image_wrapper` fixes your varying image size problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however I actually need the images to be varying size. The project requires them to be true to their original size.